# will_paginate current page is always 1

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Im using `will_paginate` and the problem Im having is when I click on a specific page number in the `will_paginate` selection. The page reloads with the `page=2` if clicking `2` on the selection for example. However on the selection it is still selected as page `1`. The selection never changes.

[image]

```html
<%= will_paginate @reservations %>
```

I removed the css from the pagination and still having the same problem.

```rails
@reservations = user.reservations.order(updated_at: :desc).page(params[:page_pending]).per_page(10)
```

also tried:

```rails
@reservations = user.reservations.order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page_pending]).per_page(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change query in the Controller --> "index action" to this?

```
@reservations = user.reservations.order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

Comment: yes i had the pagenate with page instead but i also tried with paginate. Ill update the top question with how my model call looks like.

Comment: Okay so i figured it out! you can update and ill make yours the answer.. I have to change the params name from `:page_pending` to `:page`. I had that param there instead because i thought you could make up that param to be anyname if you were to add multiple will_paginates on one page, but this seems to break the selection.. So the problem was from the index action like you said thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome, i don't know what you mean with the `:page_pending`  or multiple  will_paginates.

If you want more control i'll advise you to take a look at [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)

Comment: for instance i used to have 3 different `@reservations` one for pending, completed and expired.  so 3 different lists on one page `@reservations_pending` @resservations_expired` etc.  so the param[:page] could be chaged to params[:page_pending] or params[:page_completed] that way they dont conflict with eachother.. however i have it all wrong so i did it all on a separate page. off topic but ya haha thank you!

Comment: You are right, it could work with Kaminari. For will_paginate i don't see the option to change the paginator param.

Comment: aww okay yea thats good to know! makes sense i was using both. but they seem to conflict without some code in the .config, So my next project when i get to that ill remember kaminari for that purpose! thanks!